# How do I append a 2D array to the end of a named range?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Using VBA, I need to keep adding new values to a named range, *"rng_SplitWords_Word"*.
My new data is collected in VBA into a 2D array, *"DmpAllArr"*.

Currently, when I run my macro, the named range cells get overwritten with the new values of the array. This is the code:

```
DmpAllArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(DmpAllArr)
Range("rng_SplitWords_Word").Resize(UBound(DmpAllArr, 1)).Value = DmpAllArr
```

My goal is not to overwrite the named range values, but rather to append the array values to the existing named range. Though I have a few ideas of how to accomplish this technically, I cannot figure out how to implement them using VBA. They are as follows:

1. Save the existing data from *"rng_SplitWords_Word"* into a variant; use "ReDim Preserve" to resize *DmpAllArr*, and append the variant to *DmpAllArr*. Then clear *"rng_SplitWords_Word"* of all data and write *DmpAllArr* to it.
2. Somehow, ***append*** *DmpAllArr* to the end of *"rng_SplitWords_Word"*

Since "Append," "concatenate," and "join" don't work on 2D arrays, I don't know how to proceed.

I tried using .End(xlUp) to write the array to the row after the last of *"rng_SplitWords_Word"* but that didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Range("rng_SplitWords_Word").Offset(Range("rng_SplitWords_Word").Rows.Count).Resize(UBound(DmpAllArr, 1)).Value = DmpAllArr`?

Comment: This worked perfectly. Please add this as an answer.

Comment: @ScottCraner Can you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

### Append Array

- It is assumed that `rng_SplitWords_Word` is a one-column range and that `DmpAllArr` is a 2D one-based one-column array.

```vb
Sub AppendToNamedRange()
    
    Const RangeName As String = "rng_SplitWords_Word"
    
    Dim DmpAllArr As Variant: DmpAllArr = Array("A", "B", "C", "D")
    DmpAllArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(DmpAllArr)
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = UBound(DmpAllArr, 1)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Names(RangeName).RefersToRange.Worksheet
    
    With ws.Range(RangeName)
        Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then
            Set lCell = .Cells(1)
        Else
            Set lCell = lCell.Offset(1)
        End If
        lCell.Resize(rCount).Value = DmpAllArr
        .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + rCount).Name = RangeName
    End With
    
    MsgBox "New Range Address: " & ws.Range(RangeName) _
        .Address(0, 0), vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: `ws.Range("rng_SplitWords_Word")` will error if the scope of the named range is workbook as it does not belong to a worksheet.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I'm not sure that's right. Tested with a workbook-scoped named range "foobar" and  `Dim ws As Worksheet`, `Set ws = Sheet1`, `Debug.Print ws.Range("foobar").Address`.

Comment: @BigBen I stand corrected.  If the workbook scoped range is actually on the sheet it will not error, but if it is workbook scoped not using the worksheet would be more robust as the sheet can be changed through the UI and then it would error, in my opinion.

Comment: I completely agree with that.

Comment: rng_SplitWords_Word is a 2-column range as is DmpAllArr. I didn't try this solution because @ScottCraner gave a much simpler solution that worked, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

This will append the values and resize the named range.

```
DmpAllArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(DmpAllArr)
With Range("rng_SplitWords_Word")
    .Offset(.Rows.Count).Resize(UBound(DmpAllArr, 1)).Value = DmpAllArr
    .Resize(UBound(DmpAllArr, 1) + .Rows.Count).Name = "rng_SplitWords_Word"
End With
```

Comment: This offset it too much, a few rows beneath the table that the named range is part of.

Comment: Didn't know I could set the name like this so I stole the idea to use it in my solution.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I've learned a bunch from your posts myself.